# For Loop, how to skip iterations

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to figure out how to skip iterations on a `For` loop. I did some research and found that I could use `Continue For`, but that does not solve my issue. Here an example of what I want to do:

```
For i As Long = 1 to 7 Step 1
    If (i= 2, 5 and 7) Then
        'perform this action
    Else
        'perform other action.
    End If
Next i
```

I worked out the following, but unfortunately it works for the `<= 2` and the `Else` part of my loop and for the `5` and `7`, performs the same action as what I asked to do on the `Else` part.

```
For i As Long = 1 To 7 Step 1
    If (i <= 2 AndAlso 5 AndAlso 7) Then
        strRange = ("A:D")
    Else
        strRange = ("A:A")
    End If

    xlRefSheets = ClientSheets(i)

    With xlRefSheets
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
        .Range(strRange).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: `If (i <=2 AndAlso 5 AndAlso 7)` is not going to evaluate the way you probably think it is....

Comment: Please put Option Strict On at the top of your code file or set it in your project's properties.  Your If condition should not compile as it is expecting a Boolean expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about restating the `if` clause to

```
If (i <= 2) or (i = 5) or ( i =7)  Then
   ...
```

So your code becomes:

```
  For i As Long = 1 To 7 Step 1
    If (i <= 2) OR (i = 5) OR (i = 7) Then
        strRange = ("A:D")
    Else
        strRange = ("A:A")
    End If

    xlRefSheets = ClientSheets(i)
    With xlRefSheets
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
        .Range(strRange).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End With
  Next i
```